# Cannot POST strings containing fragmented HTML tags

Tags: ajax, apache, post, underscore.js

I'm making an ajax call to POST a string to a shared hosting server I rent from Namecheap.com. I cannot seem to POST a stirng that contains some fragmented HTML tags such as `<b><b`, `<tag><tag<tag`. When I do this, I get a 403 Forbidden error. I tried the same thing using the escape function from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), but the result was the same.

Here is the code I am using.

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/test.php',
    data : {
        pass : '<b><b' // pass : _.escape('<b><b') gives the same result
    }
})
.done(function (res) {
    console.debug(res);
})
.fail(function (err,textStatus,errorThrown) {
    console.debug('failed');
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

$password = $_POST['pass'];
echo $password;

?>
```

I tested this on XAMPP Linux on my local machine and this did not happen. Why is this happening?

Comment: What happens if you try to access the page with your browser? 403 still? It looks like a file permission issue, try to change the file perms to something like 755 or what fits your purpose.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the contents using `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: I always access it through browser. I changed the permission of the files to 755, but no luck. `encodeURIComponent` did not work, either.

Comment: As a quick and dirty fix, you can probably base64 encode it to dodge the server's XSS prevention.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: @SamDufel Thanks, that's a great idea. I could also fix this by double escaping it. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly running into some sort of ill-conceived "security" feature of your web host. Contact their support staff.

Comment: Seems like this is the case. This is very sad. I will be contacting the support team. By the way, will there be any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has the same issue, I <s>fixed</s> (See EDIT) this by double escaping the text as in `_.escape(_.escape('<b><b'))`. This will output `&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;b.`

Sam Deufel also suggested me to use base64 encoding. I think this will work, too.

**EDIT: I found that JavaScript statements such as `alert()` or `document.write()` are also not allowed to be POSTed via ajax on Namecheap hosting servers. So double escaping it does not always work. Using base64 or similar methods is probably better.**